# Built in Method for chunking a NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dask

I have a large amount of data in NetCDF4 files, and I am trying to write a script to dynamically chunk this data to hold as much in memory as possible, do calculations on it and save the results, then move on to the next chunk.

An example of what I am trying to do. Say I have an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 15, 51))  # Call these x, y, and z coordinates
```

And I only want to read ten of the x coordinates at a time, like this:

```
placeholder = 0
for i in range(10, 101, 10):
    tmp_array = arr[placeholder:i, :, :]
    # Do calculations here and save results to file or database
    placeholder += 10
```

Is there some sort of built-in method for this? In this simple example it works pretty well, but as things get more complicated this seems like it could get to be a headache for me to manage all of this myself. I am aware of Dask, but it is unhelpful to me in this situation because I am not doing array operations with the data. Although Dask could be useful to me if it had methods to deal with this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the complexity and increase the robustness by implementing a lazy generator that encapsulates the computation you're worried about and just returns the chunk at each step. Something like this perhaps:

```
def spliterate(buf, chunk):
    for start in range(0, len(buf), chunk):
        yield buf[start:start + chunk]
```

Using it is pretty straightforward:

```
for tmp in spliterate(arr, 10):
    # do calculations on tmp, don't worry about bookkeeping
```

Comment: So I like the look of this solution and it seems to work well with what I am trying to accomplish. So this generator that is returned doesn't actually read the slice into memory until it is called in the for loop, correct? I haven't actually used a generator before so I'm just trying to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Wade. Assuming that that's how your HDF package works, that will be the case. A normal numpy array exists only in memory to begin with. The generator will not access a chunk until the loop gets to it. Previous chunks will be garbage collected. For an in-memory numpy array, the chunk would be a view that wouldn't allocate a copy of the data.

Comment: @julesG.M.  I don't believe your edit is particularly useful so I rolled it back. If you feel it's important, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: yes, it's wrong like that

Comment: `buff.size` is `np.prod(buff.shape)` instead of `buff.shape[0]` which is what it should be, as you are iterating on the first dimension of the array. `len(buff) == buff.shape[0]`, and also compatible with regular lists and potentially other stuff

Comment: It currently returns a bunch of empty arrays when the array is multidimensional because `buff.size` is larger than buff.shape[0]

Comment: @JulesG.M.  I reverted the call to `len`. You make a good point

Answer (score 2):

The Dask documentation shows how to create chunked arrays for just the kind of computation you have in mind, for the case of hdf5 files: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#numpy-slicing . Your netCDF4 case may or may not work identically, but the section further down about `delayed` will do the trick, if not.

Having made your dask-array, you will want to use the [map_blocks](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks) method for the "do something with each chunk" operation (this expects to get some output back), loop over the contents of the `.blocks` attribute, or use `.to_delayed()` to do arbitrary things with each piece. Exactly which is right for you depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html?highlight=split#numpy.split), which takes an array and either a chunk size or a list of indices at which to perform the split. Your case would be `np.split(arr, 10)`, giving you a list of 10 arrays of shape `(10, 15, 51)`.

Note that an exception is raised if the axis cannot be equally divided, e.g., if you asked for chunks of size 9. If you want to split into nearly-equal chunks, without raising, you can use [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) instead.

Comment: But wouldn't this require the entire array to be held in memory in once? I am reading the big array from file, sorry if the example is unclear in that

Comment: Ahh, that wasn't clear. Yes, this method would hold the whole thing in memory, as a list of arrays. If you want a lazy version of `np.split`, you could use something from the `itertools` module in the standard library. Something like the `grouper` method from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools-recipes) would work.